# CasperJS doesn't upload file when using sendKeys

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div id="file-upload-div" class="widget-vsize">
  <div id="file-upload-wrapper">
    <div id="file-upload-controls" class="btn-group-sm">
      <input id="file" type="file" multiple="" style="display: inline;">
      <span class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 6px;">
        <button id="upload-submit" class="btn btn-default-ext" style="float: right;width: 33px;" type="submit">
        <div class="progress" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="file-upload-results-row"><div>
```

and I need to upload gist file from my local system using CasperJS and below is my CasperJS code for file uploading

```
casper.then(function(){
    casper.evaluate(function () {
        var element = document.getElementById('file');
        this.sendKeys(element, '/home/prateek/Download/Notebook 43.R');
        this.wait(3000)
    });
    this.click({ type : 'css' , path : '#upload-submit'});
    this.echo('file has been uploaded')
});
```

but still the above CasperJS code is not working. I mean the file is not getting uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one it will work

```
casper.then(function () {
var fileName = 'Uploading file path';
this.evaluate(function (fileName) {
    __utils__.findOne('input[type="file"]').setAttribute('value', fileName)
}, {fileName: fileName});

this.echo('Name=' + this.evaluate(function () {
        return __utils__.findOne('input[type="file"]').getAttribute('name')
    }));

this.echo('Value=' + this.evaluate(function () {
        return __utils__.findOne('input[type="file"]').getAttribute('value')
}));

this.page.uploadFile('input[type="file"]', fileName);
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.click(x(".//*[@id='upload-to-notebook']"));
    this.wait(5000, function () {
        this.click(x(".//*[@id='upload-submit']"));
    });
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.wait(5000);
    this.capture('screenshots/FileUploadDialogueFilled.png');
        this.test.assertVisible('#progress-bar', 'Progress Bar Rendered');
        this.waitUntilVisible(x('//*[contains(text(), "uploaded")]'), function then() { 
            console.log("Survey Upload Complete");
            this.capture('screenshots/UploadCompleteConfirm.png');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a file with PhantomJS' [`page.uploadFile()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html). Since CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS, you can directly access the `page` instance through `casper.page`:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.page.uploadFile('#file', '/home/prateek/Download/Notebook 43.R');
    this.click('#upload-submit');
    this.echo('file has been uploaded');
});
```

I doubt that you need a `wait` before submitting the form, but if you do, then you need to keep in mind that all `then*` and `wait*` functions are asynchronous step functions and are executed at the end of the current step. Use this:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.page.uploadFile('#file', '/home/prateek/Download/Notebook 43.R');
    this.wait(3000, function(){
        this.click('#upload-submit');
        this.echo('file has been uploaded');
    });
});
```

---

Other problems:

`casper.evaluate()` is the sandboxed page context. It has no access to variables defined outside. All values must be explicitly passed. `this` inside of it refers to `window` and not to `casper`. It means that you cannot call `casper.sendKeys()` or `casper.wait()` directly inside of it. I suggest, you read up what it means [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) and [here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate).

Comment: but the problem is, this page.uploadFile('#file', '/home/prateek/Download/Notebook 43.R'); this line is not selecting the specified file from the system

Comment: Well, it should work. Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: yeah, i registered but it is showing '0 Javascript errors found' and also test script is passed, but the problem is it is not selecting the file which i have mentioned

Comment: do you know any suggestions/solutions for this problem

Comment: @ Artjom, i tried with all my prior knowledge. But i still couldn't found the solution for it